# AppEng Py Flexi :: Long running request :: 502 error

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine

My app (py3, app engine flexi) receives a web request > runs BQ query > fetches data > processes data (not very CPU intensive!) > returns response.

The request can be invoke by

- directly trying the URL in browser
- or by cron job invoking a URL Job

Due to nature of BQ query:

- I’m certain the request will take >30sec to process (roughly 2-5 min.)
- I’m not concerned with volume of concurrent request, only few request will come in at same time (<10)

I’m getting [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:7) error which I believe I managed to solve by tweaking [timeout](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#timeout) settings in gunicorn.conf.py. But the nginx continues to return `502 error` in response (and cron job status end in Failed)

Can someone share why I continue to get 502 error and which parameter (in app.yaml or my application PY code) I should tweak to manage this timeout? And best practices how to handle such requests that you are certain gonna take 2-5 minutes (or even longer!)

Alternatively, I’m thinking to create Cloud Function endpoint, now that CF supports PY (and has support for [higher timeouts as high as 9 minutes](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#timeout)..)

Answer (score 2):

Even if you know your request will take <9 minutes, it's not good practice to keep the client app waiting, as there are multiple ways the request could be interrupted.

The way to do it is through jobs/operations (exactly as [BQ](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert) and most Google APIs do it). As soon as the query is started (the BQ job is inserted), you store the job ID returned by BQ and generate a new one for your app (e.g. in datastore).

Then the client app starts polling for this operation. Every 5 seconds it asks your app (or your function) if your operation is finished. Your app then retrieves the BQ job ID from the storage, [checks in the BQ API if that job is finished](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/get), and returns an unfinished status in case it is not.

Once the app checks if the job on the BQ side is finished, [it can retrieve the data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/getQueryResults), process it, and return the result.

This will make the process much more idempotent and resilient, as well as avoiding to keep all of those connections open, which is not scalable at all.

With an architecture like that, you can deploy this anywhere you like (GAE, functions, ...) and it should still work. For ease of use, I would use Google Cloud Functions with Datastore (to store your operation IDs), but in a situation like this, it mostly depends on what you're more comfortable using.

Comment: Hi @Jofre, Thanks you very much for your guidance. This starts to make make perfect sense now. In my app, request (low volume, mostly 50 per day) will mostly come via scheduled cron jobs, so the the architect i'm thinking of is:- use Pub / Sub as intermediary to store the query Job ID (instead of Datastore).

Comment: STEP1) cron job-1 calls the end point (my app running on app engine) to begin the query job, publishing the BQ job.insert ID to publisher

Comment: STEP2) cron job-2 calls another end point after 10 min. (with max 5 retries), code in this end end point acts as subscriber, fetching the query job id, checking the job.get status, getting job.getQueryResults results processing data and returning the response to cron job caller. My question is, the Pub/Sub doc says: “The subscriber is non-blocking, so we must keep the main thread from exiting to allow it to process messages in the background.” - meaning, I must put a wait loop for 1min. or so (Or whatever max. client request timeout for AppEngine allows) in subscriber end point

Comment: The point I would change is the last one. To return the computed data to the end-user you should not keep everything running. After you have processed the data you can store the results (e.g. in a bucket under `gs://<bucketId>/results/<jobId>`), and access them directly instead of having to keep a thread open to return the results to the caller. At the moment of job reation, you'll know the location of the results once the processing is finished, so there is no need to keep anything running.

Comment: Thanks for correction, AFAIK, during job creation (`job.insert`) you can only specify to store query results in BQ table. Can I also specify query results destination to be GCS bucket?. I'm half way through implementation and find a same challenge...

Comment: A) initiate query > publish query job_id to pubs topic> the request ends there...

Comment: B) after 30 min. another request to my app (pub sub subscriber) pulls the query job_id from the Topic > use this job_id to fetch query results from temp. BQ table where query results is stored... but reached a time out :( [when running locally everything runs within 50sec.]. I did extend worker timeout to 300sec in gunicorn config file (not ideal! but just to get things going for now...)

Comment: I posted another query with screenshots when I encounter this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51983085/appengine-app-querying-bigquery-error-upstream-prematurely-closed-connectio