# AppEngine app querying BigQuery :: [error] upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

My application:

- **STEP1**: fetches BQ job_id pulished to a pubsusb topic.
- **STEP2**: checks if the job.state is DONE or not (most times its’s already DONE!)
- **STEP3**: if the job is finished, fetches the query results (60K rows x50 columns, all floating digits)
- **STEP4**: processes query result data and uploads to Google Analytics (via Data Import API)

Locally on my PC all works fine. However, when running on AppEngine Flexi environment (Python3 and using CLinet Libraries) I’m having problems on **Step3** fetching the query results.

I tried 3 ways and from logs I can see it’s these steps where the application gets stuck and returns 502 BAD Gateway:

- ver1:

  `df = job.to_dataframe()  //STUCK here`
- ver2:

  `result = job.result() // SUCCESS`

  `rows = list(result) //STUCK here`
- ver3:

  `schema = [r.name for r in result.schema]  // SUCCESS

  `print("schema fetched: ",schema)  // SUCCESS

  `pages = [page for page in result.pages]  //STUCK here

  `print("pages fetched: ",len(pages))

Stackdriver gives following logs:

> [error] 32#32: *7316 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 216.XX.YY.ZZ, server: , request: "GET /ml_models/dev_poll_results/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.1:8080/ml_models/dev_poll_results/", host: "serato-big-query.appspot.com"

Any help, any guidance will be highly appreciable pls.
[image]

**UPDATE**

From Stackdriver Logging I see BQ does get datasets:tables:data reques. Oddly, `protoPayload.serviceData.tableDataListRequest` field is empty. Usually it's populated with `maxResults` `startRow` field. Makes meeting feel, could there be an issue with communicating large results between BQ and AppEngine app 
[image]

Comment: Without more info, smells like a timeout setting in the serving stack.  Do the logs from the real backend (not the nginx log) tell you more?  How long does the request take in your local environment?

Comment: Thanks, I updated my original post wit more info (screenshot). I do have everything under try:, except: block. Can you share how to obtain more logs or guide me pls? A) Also at each application step I'm writing print() statements and can see the query results schema is successfully fetched. It's only when making a request for table data (temp table where query results are written) the program / request hangs and after a while get this error. B) Also Gunicorn worker timeout is set to 300sec (not ideal! But just to get it work meanwhile)

Comment: re: timeouts, running locally everything takes approx. 50sec. (+/-10sec). Fetching BQ query job_id form pubs > Getting the query results from BQ > Processing the data > Upload to GA

Comment: The lack of payload in tableDataListRequest isn't unusual if you're using the natural cursor-based approach rather than an explicit offset+rowcount.  A single page of data should return ~10MB or less.  Perhaps restricting the data volume size with an outer LIMIT query may help diagnose the end to end?